# How to plot stacked bar graph using R

Tags: r, bar-chart

How to create a stacked bar graph using R-Language with x-axis is `CODE`, the `TYPE` is stacked in one `CODE` and the y-axis is `COUNT`. I have tried it since last 2 weeks and I never get a proper bar graph yet.

```
COUNT      TYPE    CODE
   31        GJ     PUM
  161        GO     PUM
   12       GL2     PUM
    9        GJ     SOP
    8        GO     SOP
    8       GL2     SOP
  456        OL     SOP
  912        KL     SKQ
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why does it leave you unsatisfied? I suggest a careful read of `?barplot`.

Comment: I tried a method from this link http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/creating-stacked-barplot-and-grouped-barplot-in-r-using-base-graphics-no-ggplot2 and when I do it, the data will be not arranged properly since the data in the sample have a kind of pattern whereby my data do not have fixed pattern. 

It will generate the stacked bargraph but the data in the graph not reflect the original data. I really new to this R-Language. @jbaums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with `base` R.

```
d <- read.table(text='COUNT      TYPE    CODE
   31        GJ     PUM
  161        GO     PUM
   12       GL2     PUM
    9        GJ     SOP
    8        GO     SOP
    8       GL2     SOP
  456        OL     SOP
  912        KL     SKQ', header=T)

# Choose some colours
library(RColorBrewer)
colrs <- brewer.pal(nlevels(d$TYPE), 'Set3')

# Plot that
par(mar=c(4, 4, 2, 6))
tab <- xtabs(COUNT ~ TYPE + CODE, d)
barplot(tab, las=1, col=colrs, yaxp=c(0, 1000, 5), ylim=c(0, 1000), ylab='Count')
box()

# Clipping off for legend
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(par('usr')[2], par('usr')[4], row.names(tab), bty='n', fill=colrs)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the the solution. Actually, the data I get is from a query from my database by using sqlQuery function. how do I retrieve the data if the data from the query instead like you did by using read.table function? @jbaums

Comment: @SyazwanZakaria - See my edit. If your data are in a matrix or data.frame, you should be able to pass a formula to `xtabs` describing the relationship between the counts and the two variables. If it still doesn't work, you should make the structure of your data more clear in your question.

Comment: This is my query 

test <- sqlQuery(con, "select count, type, code from ov group by code, type order by code, type") and the result is what I posted in the question. 

How do I retrieve the data from that query like read.table function. @jbaums

Comment: @SyazwanZakaria - I don't understand what you mean... Is `test` a data.frame? If so, where I have used `d`, just substitute in `test`.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `geom_bar` from `ggplot`:

```
# your data
df <- read.table(text='COUNT      TYPE    CODE
   31        GJ     PUM
  161        GO     PUM
   12       GL2     PUM
    9        GJ     SOP
    8        GO     SOP
    8       GL2     SOP
  456        OL     SOP
  912        KL     SKQ', header=TRUE)
# plot
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(CODE, COUNT, fill=TYPE)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  theme_bw(base_size=16)
print(p)
```

Comment: Nice solution. Actually, the data I get is from a query from my database by using sqlQuery function. May I know how to retrieve the data from the query like you did by using read.table function? @shadow

Comment: This is my query

test <- sqlQuery(con, "select count, type, code from ov group by code, type order by code, type")

and the result is what I posted in the question. How do I retrieve the data from that query like you did by using read.table function. @shadow